# Webscraping event name, location, price

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

[This is the website I am scraping.](https://www.kpbs.org/events/search/?unifyevents=true&vertical_events=true&base_arts=true&base_category=137)

I am using BeautifulSoup in Jupyter, I was wondering how I can scrape this web site for event name, location, and price. I found their location in the Inspect tool.

Right now I found the event name but I feel like my process is long and unnecessary.

My plan was to put it all scraped event data from this page into a data frame.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

kpbs_link = "https://www.kpbs.org/events/search/?unifyevents=true&vertical_events=true&base_arts=true&base_category=137/"
page = requests.get(kpbs_link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text)

events = soup.find_all('h4', {"class": "list_title"})
```

I feel like placing it into an array and cleaning it is very long and tedious, is there any was faster, and how. I have **scraped** data from Wikipedia using beautiful soup but his website was much more tedious.

Answer (score 2):

You can try and run the below code. You need to pay attention to the cost element since it is not present for all the events so I have put a condition to handle that. It extracts the list elements from the page for name, location, and price of the event:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
name = []
location = []
price = []

url = "https://www.kpbs.org/events/search/?unifyevents=true&vertical_events=true&base_arts=true&base_category=137"  # no trailing /
try:
    page = requests.get(url)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

    items = soup.find_all("li", {"class": "item"})
    for item in items:
        name.append(item.find('h4', {"class": "list_title"}).text.strip())
        location.append(item.find('p', {"class": "list_place"}).text.strip())
        try:
            price.append(item.find('p', {"class": "cost"}).text.strip())
        except:
            price.append('NA')

    final_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'title': name,
     'location': location,
     'price': price
    })
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    print("continuing....")
```